# How to get defined table name in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with several sheets with assigned to them alliances. One of value on one sheet is calculating by using code below:

```
VLOOKUP(D10; lst_table_col; 4;00);
```

It doesn't matter that `VLOOKUP` function do, that matters is what exactly sheet behind `lst_table_col`. The problem is that this excel file doesn't contain any `lst_table_col` sheet. I'm looking for any solution: by just mouse, vba - whatever.

I believe my question is very easy, but this situation confuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a table called `lst_table_col`

Because if it was a direct reference to an Excel Range, you would see something like this in the formula :

> `SheetName!R1C1:R10C4`

or

> `A1:D10`

so check in **Formula Tabs** -> **Name Manager** to find it! ;)

Here is the link for the tutorial provided by @Rocketq : https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmmanage_names_by_using_the_name_manage